# Use the latest version of a Google Code Java project? (Build jar with Maven Eclipse plugin?)

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I would like to use r124 of [gwtquery-ui](http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-ui/) in my GWT/GAE project. How can I do this? Maybe I could check out the code and build a jar in Eclipse, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) as it looks like that's where builds are pushed.

It doesn't look like that version is pushed to their [maven repository](http://gwtquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/com/google/gwt/gwtquery-ui/).  I'd suggest checking a copy of the source out, building locally and then just checking it into your local maven repository.

This should be as simple as:

```
svn checkout http://gwtquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ gwtquery-ui-read-only
cd gwtquery-ui-read-only
mvn install
```

Now a copy will be installed in your local maven repository and you should just be able to point [Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html) at it (either via some sort of integration or just via the JAR file on disk).

Comment: What does it mean for a copy to be "installed"? I don't know anything about maven.

Comment: Also, I have the Eclipse maven plugin and I'm not sure how to use it to build a jar.

Comment: Solution: use Maven to build an Eclipse project (.classpath and .project files), then use add a project reference to the classpath in Eclipse.